# Cribbage muggins on the final hand

Tags: cribbage

Score after last pegging:
Player 1 (dealer) = 120
Player 2 = 114

Player 2 counts his hand first and says he has 10 points which puts him at 124 BUT, he missed 6 points in his hand. Does player 1 get those muggins and thus win the match with 126 points?

Answer (score 2):

The *muggins* claim by Player 1 cannot be made until the peg is moved by Player 2 and released - which in this case wins the game.

Even if this is not a **written official rule**, it is the only sane way to play *muggins*. There must needs be an official *start* to the *muggins* claiming period, which definitively indicates that *Player 1* is satisfied with his hand count. Moving the peg and releasing it is exactly that.

---

**Update**

Here is the official [*American Cribbage Congress* **Rules of Muggins**](http://www.cribbage.org/NewSite/rules/rule10.asp). It specifically states (**my emphasis**):

> ### **Rule 10.2. Situations That Apply**
>
> Except for the situations listed in rule 10.3, muggins is applied to the **underpegging of the full value** of any points during the play or scoring of the points in the hand or crib.

and further down

> **c.** For points missed in a hand or crib:
>
> > **(1)** The dealer must call muggins **after the pone has finished pegging the score** or states there is no score and before the pone's hand is mixed with other cards or the total count of the dealer's hand is announced.